# QuerySet model Category, Product and ProductImage

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

Ola, me ajudem a montar esse queryset.

Resumidamente o model
`model.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created = models.DateField('Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField('Modificado em', auto_now=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Identificador', max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('catalog.Category', verbose_name='Categoria')
    description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField('Preço', decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = CloudinaryField('Imagem', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField('Descrição', max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
```

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte:
No meu "site" o cliente escolhe a categoria. Ai é listada todos os produtos da categoria. Até esse ponto eu consegui retornar os produtos com o nome, preco, etc. A duvida é:
**como farei para buscar a imagem desse produto?**

Vejam a 
`view.py`

```
from django.views import generic

class CategoryListView(generic.ListView):
    """
    Lista os produtos de determinada categoria (Bolo ou Biscoitos)
    """
    template_name = 'catalog/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
       return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_category'] = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        # tenho a categoria
        # pela categoria consigo achar os produtos
        # achando os produto consigo achar as imagens
        # e ai como que faz ?
        return context
```

resumi o codigo, mas quem quiser ver o projeto completo acessem
https://github.com/leonardocintra/cleonice

Grato!

Comment: dê uma olhada neste github...vc achará o que precisa.
https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/ecommerce-2

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro atualize seu model ProductImage com `related_name`:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
     image = CloudinaryField('Imagem', blank=True, null=True)
     description = models.CharField('Descrição', max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
```

Assim fica possível fazer uma query assim:

```
 product = Product.objects.get(category=category)
 images = product.images.all()
```

Isso é possível devido o atributo `related_name`, caso não use o atributo é possível fazer dessa forma:

```
 product = Product.objects.get(category=category)
 images = product.productimagem_set.all()
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Hugo, obrigado. Uma duvida: Como irei percorrer a imagem no meu template?

Comment: Fiz assim: return Product.objects.prefetch_related('images').filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])